# How to handle this thread synchronization issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I need a solutions for one data-race scenario and proper synchronization.

```
struct download_info {
    int download_id;
    notification_data noti_data;
};

download_info* global_info;


// Will be called from download_module
void download_progress_callback(int download_id, int progress_val) { 
    global_info->current_val = progress_val;
    update_notification(global_info);
}

// will be called from notification_module
notification_timeout_callback() {
    // Here I need to modify the notification_look
    // [1]. So I will delete the noti_data
    // [2]. create a new noti_data just to that of existing one with same notification_id
    // [3]. update the look of notification
    update_notification(global_info);
}
```

**Here there is race-condition and synchronization in both these function.**

Now for overcoming this race-condition & synchronization, I can use `pthread_mutex_t`. But I have two problems in using it.

1. `download_progress_callback()` is getting called too frequently, so
   there will be lots of waiting.
2. If I use `pthread_mutex_trylock()` and there may be a situation where I will not get further progress notification and will not come to know if the download is completed.

Any suggestion for handling this case. I have cut-off lots for detail, so if anything is not clear, please ask.

Comment: It sounds like a GUI progress update, maybe try a slower update cycle, so only set `global_info->current_val` in larger increments? Alternatively try use a queue.

Comment: yes, it's a system notification. can you please tell something more about queue which you have mentioned.

Comment: There are several concurrent queues out there (e.g. [TBB](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_queue_cls.htm)). Thinking a little more here, maybe a `condition_variable` and a timeout would be easier for the GUI to handle. You mention speed is a concern, does changing the mutex to an `atomic<>` improve the situation?

Comment: If I use mutex, then global data will be protected. But suppose, when lock has been acquired by notification_timeout_callback() and I have got 100% download completed event in download_progess_callback(), then pthread_mutex_trylock() will be skipped, and i'll never get download-finished.

Comment: You may need to then identify the completion as a special case in the code, either another variable, or a "forced" completion value.

Comment: ok thanks Niall. Is there any standard solution for such threading problem.

Comment: I don't think so (for the special value)